# Order of @Value insertion in spring is ambiguous

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a bean in spring in which i try to inject some values from a property file.

This is not an unusual task for me, i have done this multiple times without an error, but now, i have this code

```
@Component("cmHeaderChecker")
public class CustomerManagementHeaderChecker extends AbstractHeaderChecker {

private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomerManagementHeaderChecker.class);

protected String fileSeparator;

@Value("${customerManagement.file.input.separator}")
public void setFileSeparator(String separator) {
    LOGGER.error("set separator");
    this.fileSeparator = separator;
    super.setSeparator(separator);
}

@Value("${customerManagement.file.input.headers}")
public void setExpectedHeader(String expectedHeader) {
    LOGGER.error("set header");
    super.setExpectedHeader(expectedHeader.split(normalizeSplitter(fileSeparator)));
}

@javax.annotation.Resource(name = "cmReportGenerator")
public void setReportGenerator(ReportGenerator reportGenerator) {
    super.setReportGenerator(reportGenerator);
}
}
```

if i run this code in debug mode, `fileSeparator` is set before the `expectedHeader`, and all works ok

if i run this code in run mode, `fileSeparator` is not set before the `expectedHeader` and it throws a null pointer exception

i have a bit of trouble understanding this. can you please provide some explanation about this

---

if i change the following methods, it works in both run and debug mode either way, but this still does not explain the quite odd behaviour. and i don't quite like the setters now

```
@Value("${customerManagement.file.input.separator}")
protected String fileSeparator;

@Value("${customerManagement.file.input.headers}")
public void setExpectedHeader(String expectedHeader) {
    LOGGER.error("set header");
    super.setSeparator(fileSeparator); 
   super.setExpectedHeader(expectedHeader.split(normalizeSplitter(fileSeparator)));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java/Spring do not guarantee anything in terms of ordering in this context. Thus you should not depend on a predictable ordering.

You best bet is to remove all logic from the setters of your parameters (they should just be used to set the value) and put that logic in a @PostConstruct.

The PostConstruct is guaranteed to run after all the parameter values have been set.